# 301 Redirect Rules for a Blog Migration

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to implement 3 redirect rules for a blog migration where each page will be shifted to a sub-folder structure. It currently sits at a sub-domain.

I can't really screw this one up and want to make sure I nail the correct generic rules for the 3 type of existing URLs:

**Homepage**

Current:

```
https://blog.lang.example.com
```

Goal:

```
https://www.example.com/lang-country/news/
```

**Category**

Current:

```
https://blog.lang.example.com/category/category-name
```

Goal:

```
https://www.example.com/lang-country/news/category/category-name
```

**Post**

Current:

```
https://blog.lang.example.com/yyy/mm/dd/article-name
```

Goal:

```
https://www.example.com/lang-country/news/yyy/mm/dd/article-name
```

Is this something you can help?

Comment: This is basically one rule. Did you already try something?

Comment: Where does this subdomain point to on the filesystem? Somewhere different to the main domain? Is the `lang` subdomain, literally the word "lang", or is this variable and should be copied through to the subdirectory? ie. `<lang>-country`?

Comment: @MrWhite I don't have full visibility on the filesystem - apologies, not sure how to answer this. I know that they use different CMS systems for the subdomain sites and the root domain. The goal is to bring everything under the same domain where the subdomain would be now subfolder. The lang would indeed be the language variable and so is the country - my bad not to be clear. <lang>-<country> is the correct terminology. So would be something like: en-gb, en-us, fr-fr, etc...

Comment: @PanamaJack I reckon it should be one rule only considering everything else stays the same. I'm just afraid I'm not savvy enough to even give a shot on it.

Comment: So, where does `<country>` come from? This does not seem to be present in the "current" URL structure.

Comment: @MrWhite That's right.While currently the blog subdomains URLs are broken down by language, the new URLs need to split by country - this is how the domain subfolder structure is set (there are much more countries being targeted in the domain subfolders rather than existing subdomain languages). For countries that have a language where there is no current blog implemented, what will show up is the english version.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have other URLs that you don't want to be redirected then you can do something like what you require with a single redirect near the top of the `.htaccess` file in the subdomain's document root.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/%1-country/news/$1 [R,L]
```

Where `%1` is a backreference to the *lang* subdomain in the requested host.

However, you still have the problem of where `country` should come from in the target URL, since this is not present in the source URL. You will either need to default this to something or implement some kind of lookup based on the *language*. This would need server config access (to configure a `RewriteMap`) if you wanted to do this in `.htaccess`. Or, you implement this redirect entirely in your server-side script (eg. PHP).

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect once you have tested that everything is working OK (if a 301 is required). 301 redirects are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.